# Trigger a click on a page in the pagetree in Backend

Tags: typo3, backend

How could I trigger in JS a click on the pageitem of TYPO3 BE pagetree by an ID of the page ?

Looking for solutions for versions 4.5 and 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

The basics are described in this document (might be slightly deprecated):

http://buzz.typo3.org/people/steffen-kamper/article/backend-navigation-in-typo3-45/

For example, to open the submodule "task center" in the "user tools" module, enter this

```
top.TYPO3.ModuleMenu.App.showModule('user_task');
```

or, *to change to the pagetree,* this

```
top.TYPO3.ModuleMenu.App.showModule('web_layout');
```

inside the firebug console. According to the author,

> The pagetree resides in top.TYPO3.Backend.NavigationContainer, the
>   content resides in top.TYPO3.Backend.ContentContainer.

I haven't really understood what you'd like to click on exactly. But it might get you started.

I think in real life (or in an html fragment in a page in the backend) you can set <a javascript:...> urls</a>

I am still trying to figure out the fine points of this javascript  myself. I for one want to also click on a select-box in the content Iframe after clicking in the Admintools/Report submodule. The first part is this:

```
top.TYPO3.ModuleMenu.App.showModule('tools_txreportsM1');
```